# How to find if calendar content provider exists

Tags: android, calendar

I am using this for adding event to calendars

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
....
startActivity(intent);
```

But how would I know if there is no provider for event (like on the emulator). I do get a ActivityNotFoundException, but can it be found before launching the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` and [`queryIntentActivities()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). If it returns an empty list, you know that a `startActivity()` on the `Intent` will result in an `ActivityNotFoundException`.